# How to change Laravel 10.2 command email output subject?

Tags: laravel

I am using `"laravel/framework": "10.22.0",`

and also the commands and scheduling system.

I have for instance

```
        $schedule->command(SomeCommand::class)
            ->weekly()->emailWrittenOutputTo(self::$reportEmails);
```

My problem is that before Laravel 10 I was receiving always subjects like `Scheduled Job Output For ['/usr/bin/php8' 'artisan' my:command]` and now I get as email subject the command description (if present).

The code that decides what the subject will be is part of the framework at:
`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php`

```
    /**
     * Get the e-mail subject line for output results.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getEmailSubject()
    {
        if ($this->description) {
            return $this->description;
        }

        return "Scheduled Job Output For [{$this->command}]";
    }
```

I created one class that extends this and injected it in the DI container but does not work because internally Laravel uses its own class while scheduling the command at

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Schedule.php`
it creates and returns instance of the original Event class inside the vendor.

How can I change the way the subject for the command output e-mails is created without having to extends many Laravel classes ?

I found the pattern very amazing for the subject as it allowed one to use filters to move all command outputs to a separate folder inside the mail server.